# Measure server response time with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, http, networking

I'd like to measure the response time of the REST API that I'm using as precise as possible to verify SLAs. I'm querying it from the `ASP.NET Core (.Net 5)` app using the `HttpClient` class. Obviously I could just wrap the call in `Stopwatch` but that will include TLS handshake and DNS lookup which I'd like to exclude. I'm betting my best guess would be using the dedicated `EventSource` as described here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-5-new-networking-improvements/ it works fine, however it's not quite clear how to correlate events which do not share the same `ActivityId` (e.g. do not have the same `EventName` and `Start/Stop` suffixes). I suppose the most precise (but not perfect of course) measurement can be received by observing time diff between `RequestContentStop` and `ResponseContentStop` events however it's not quite clear how to correlate them, the IDs look similar and can be probably calculated using some GUID byte hacks but this will also require storing these IDs in a `ConcurentDictionary` or something similar and potentially impact performance. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: What the purpose of such measurements? Client while interacts with Server can't to the request without DNS lookup (at least first) or TLS handshake (if HTTPS). Response time must be comfortable to view server responses in time, that's it. The more interesting metric to measure is RPS and correlating response time to RPS value. The less time increase at peak RPS means the more stable server. That metrics includes TLS overhead anyway. I suggest benchmarking in that way because it can show where's bottlenecks which can be eliminated before going to production.

Comment: @aepot the purpose is to be as objective as possible and to have this value constantly observed during production usage (besides the initial benchmarks that you've mentioned), also nerd curiosity :)

Comment: The objective measurement on that level is CPU/Memory profiling. There's a lot of monitoring tools to track GC jobs + object allocations + CPU load. Measurement for measurement is not a thing to do. Search for real bottlenecks not meaningless digits. Finally, you're not in realtime environment to measure the execution time from a first kick. Also that measurement won't show anything useful without proper RPS rate.

Comment: If you are looking for bottlenecks in your code, check [this blog post](https://medium.com/apaleo-engineering/how-apaleo-improves-api-performance-9c10695740c1) to see how we do it at [apaleo](https://apaleo.com/).